# WebLogic openJDK error

Tags: java, centos, weblogic

I'm trying to install WebLogic to my CentOS virtual maching.

I installed `openjdk-1.8.0 version`.

when I try to install `fmw_12.2.1.1.0_wls_quick.jar` which is quick installer to linux, 
with code `java -jar fmw_12.2.1.1.0_wls_quick.jar` there is error.

> OpenJDK JVM not support this platform.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [supported JVMs](https://www.google.com/search?q=osb+supported+java+versions#q=FMW+12.1.2+supported+java+versions), it states `Oracle JDK
 1.7.0_15+`, `HP JDK 7.0.3+` or `IBM JDK 1.7.0 SR4+`

Open JDK is just not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue while installing weblogic on OpenJDK.

Follow the steps below to install weblogic on your machine.

- Download Oracle JDK 7 from the below url:-

  https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html
- Install the tar.gz/rpm based jdk version based on your operating
  system.
- Verify the new version and then install weblogic. It will work.